How to pass variable from my JS file to Spring Boot Controller?
below is the code for selection of State and City in my view page (I am using Thymeleaf 3)
<div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">State</label> <select
                        onchange="print_city('state', this.selectedIndex);" id="sts"
                        name="stt"  class="form-control" required>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">City</label> <select
                        id="state" class="form-control" required>
                        <option  >Select
                            State First</option>
                    </select>
                    <script language="javascript">
                        print_state("sts");
                    </script>
                </div>

I am running a JS File to populate the selections  below is the code (this I got from GitHub)
var state_arr = new Array("Andaman & Nicobar", "Andhra Pradesh", "Arunachal Pradesh", "Assam", "Bihar", "Chandigarh", "Chhattisgarh", "Dadra & Nagar Haveli", "Daman & Diu", "Delhi", "Goa", "Gujarat", "Haryana", "Himachal Pradesh", "Jammu & Kashmir", "Jharkhand", "Karnataka", "Kerala", "Lakshadweep", "Madhya Pradesh", "Maharashtra", "Manipur", "Meghalaya", "Mizoram", "Nagaland", "Orissa", "Pondicherry", "Punjab", "Rajasthan", "Sikkim", "Tamil Nadu", "Tripura", "Uttar Pradesh", "Uttaranchal", "West Bengal");

var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0] = "";
s_a[1] = " Alipur | Andaman Island | Anderson Island | Arainj-Laka-Punga | Austinabad | Bamboo Flat | Barren Island | Beadonabad | Betapur | Bindraban | Bonington | Brookesabad | Cadell Point | Calicut | Chetamale | Cinque Islands | Defence Island | Digilpur | Dolyganj | Flat Island | Geinyale | Great Coco Island | Haddo | Havelock Island | Henry Lawrence Island | Herbertabad | Hobdaypur | Ilichar | Ingoie | Inteview Island | Jangli Ghat | Jhon Lawrence Island | Karen | Kartara | KYD Islannd | Landfall Island | Little Andmand | Little Coco Island | Long Island | Maimyo | Malappuram | Manglutan | Manpur | Mitha Khari | Neill Island | Nicobar Island | North Brother Island | North Passage Island | North Sentinel Island | Nothen Reef Island | Outram Island | Pahlagaon | Palalankwe | Passage Island | Phaiapong | Phoenix Island | Port Blair | Preparis Island | Protheroepur | Rangachang | Rongat | Rutland Island | Sabari | Saddle Peak | Shadipur | Smith Island | Sound Island | South Sentinel Island | Spike Island | Tarmugli Island | Taylerabad | Titaije | Toibalawe | Tusonabad | West Island | Wimberleyganj | Yadita";
s_a[2] = " Achampet | Adilabad | Adoni | Alampur | Allagadda | Alur | Amalapuram | Amangallu | Anakapalle | Anantapur | Andole | Araku | Armoor | Asifabad | Aswaraopet | Atmakur | B. Kothakota | Badvel | Banaganapalle | Bandar | Bangarupalem | Banswada | Bapatla | Bellampalli | Bhadrachalam | Bhainsa | Bheemunipatnam | Bhimadole | Bhimavaram | Bhongir | Bhooragamphad | Boath | Bobbili | Bodhan | Chandoor | Chavitidibbalu | Chejerla | Chepurupalli | Cherial | Chevella | Chinnor | Chintalapudi | Chintapalle | Chirala | Chittoor | Chodavaram | Cuddapah | Cumbum | Darsi | Devarakonda | Dharmavaram | Dichpalli | Divi | Donakonda | Dronachalam | East Godavari | Eluru | Eturnagaram | Gadwal | Gajapathinagaram | Gajwel | Garladinne | Giddalur | Godavari | Gooty | Gudivada | Gudur | Guntur | Hindupur | Hunsabad | Huzurabad | Huzurnagar | Hyderabad | Ibrahimpatnam | Jaggayyapet | Jagtial | Jammalamadugu | Jangaon | Jangareddygudem | Jannaram | Kadiri | Kaikaluru | Kakinada | Kalwakurthy | Kalyandurg | Kamalapuram | Kamareddy | Kambadur | Kanaganapalle | Kandukuru | Kanigiri | Karimnagar | Kavali | Khammam | Khanapur (AP) | Kodangal | Koduru | Koilkuntla | Kollapur | Kothagudem | Kovvur | Krishna | Krosuru | Kuppam | Kurnool | Lakkireddipalli | Madakasira | Madanapalli | Madhira | Madnur | Mahabubabad | Mahabubnagar | Mahadevapur | Makthal | Mancherial | Mandapeta | Mangalagiri | Manthani | Markapur | Marturu | Medachal | Medak | Medarmetla | Metpalli | Mriyalguda | Mulug | Mylavaram | Nagarkurnool | Nalgonda | Nallacheruvu | Nampalle | Nandigama | Nandikotkur | Nandyal | Narasampet | Narasaraopet | Narayanakhed | Narayanpet | Narsapur | Narsipatnam | Nazvidu | Nelloe | Nellore | Nidamanur | Nirmal | Nizamabad | Nuguru | Ongole | Outsarangapalle | Paderu | Pakala | Palakonda | Paland | Palmaneru | Pamuru | Pargi | Parkal | Parvathipuram | Pathapatnam | Pattikonda | Peapalle | Peddapalli | Peddapuram | Penukonda | Piduguralla | Piler | Pithapuram | Podili | Polavaram | Prakasam | Proddatur | Pulivendla | Punganur | Putturu | Rajahmundri | Rajampeta | Ramachandrapuram | Ramannapet | Rampachodavaram | Rangareddy | Rapur | Rayachoti | Rayadurg | Razole | Repalle | Saluru | Sangareddy | Sathupalli | Sattenapalle | Satyavedu | Shadnagar | Siddavattam | Siddipet | Sileru | Sircilla | Sirpur Kagaznagar | Sodam | Sompeta | Srikakulam | Srikalahasthi | Srisailam | Srungavarapukota | Sudhimalla | Sullarpet | Tadepalligudem | Tadipatri | Tanduru | Tanuku | Tekkali | Tenali | Thungaturthy | Tirivuru | Tirupathi | Tuni | Udaygiri | Ulvapadu | Uravakonda | Utnor | V.R. Puram | Vaimpalli | Vayalpad | Venkatgiri | Venkatgirikota | Vijayawada | Vikrabad | Vinjamuru | Vinukonda | Visakhapatnam | Vizayanagaram | Vizianagaram | Vuyyuru | Wanaparthy | Warangal | Wardhannapet | Yelamanchili | Yelavaram | Yeleswaram | Yellandu | Yellanuru | Yellareddy | Yerragondapalem | Zahirabad ";
s_a[3] = " Along | Anini | Anjaw | Bameng | Basar | Changlang | Chowkhem | Daporizo | Dibang Valley | Dirang | Hayuliang | Huri | Itanagar | Jairampur | Kalaktung | Kameng | Khonsa | Kolaring | Kurung Kumey | Lohit | Lower Dibang Valley | Lower Subansiri | Mariyang | Mechuka | Miao | Nefra | Pakkekesang | Pangin | Papum Pare | Passighat | Roing | Sagalee | Seppa | Siang | Tali | Taliha | Tawang | Tezu | Tirap | Tuting | Upper Siang | Upper Subansiri | Yiang Kiag ";
s_a[4] = " Abhayapuri | Baithalangshu | Barama | Barpeta Road | Bihupuria | Bijni | Bilasipara | Bokajan | Bokakhat | Boko | Bongaigaon | Cachar | Cachar Hills | Darrang | Dhakuakhana | Dhemaji | Dhubri | Dibrugarh | Digboi | Diphu | Goalpara | Gohpur | Golaghat | Guwahati | Hailakandi | Hajo | Halflong | Hojai | Howraghat | Jorhat | Kamrup | Karbi Anglong | Karimganj | Kokarajhar | Kokrajhar | Lakhimpur | Maibong | Majuli | Mangaldoi | Mariani | Marigaon | Moranhat | Morigaon | Nagaon | Nalbari | Rangapara | Sadiya | Sibsagar | Silchar | Sivasagar | Sonitpur | Tarabarihat | Tezpur | Tinsukia | Udalgiri | Udalguri | UdarbondhBarpeta";
s_a[5] = " Adhaura | Amarpur | Araria | Areraj | Arrah | Arwal | Aurangabad | Bagaha | Banka | Banmankhi | Barachakia | Barauni | Barh | Barosi | Begusarai | Benipatti | Benipur | Bettiah | Bhabhua | Bhagalpur | Bhojpur | Bidupur | Biharsharif | Bikram | Bikramganj | Birpur | Buxar | Chakai | Champaran | Chapara | Dalsinghsarai | Danapur | Darbhanga | Daudnagar | Dhaka | Dhamdaha | Dumraon | Ekma | Forbesganj | Gaya | Gogri | Gopalganj | H.Kharagpur | Hajipur | Hathua | Hilsa | Imamganj | Jahanabad | Jainagar | Jamshedpur | Jamui | Jehanabad | Jhajha | Jhanjharpur | Kahalgaon | Kaimur (Bhabua) | Katihar | Katoria | Khagaria | Kishanganj | Korha | Lakhisarai | Madhepura | Madhubani | Maharajganj | Mahua | Mairwa | Mallehpur | Masrakh | Mohania | Monghyr | Motihari | Motipur | Munger | Muzaffarpur | Nabinagar | Nalanda | Narkatiaganj | Naugachia | Nawada | Pakribarwan | Pakridayal | Patna | Phulparas | Piro | Pupri | Purena | Purnia | Rafiganj | Rajauli | Ramnagar | Raniganj | Raxaul | Rohtas | Rosera | S.Bakhtiarpur | Saharsa | Samastipur | Saran | Sasaram | Seikhpura | Sheikhpura | Sheohar | Sherghati | Sidhawalia | Singhwara | Sitamarhi | Siwan | Sonepur | Supaul | Thakurganj | Triveniganj | Udakishanganj | Vaishali | Wazirganj";
s_a[6] = " Chandigarh | Mani Marja";
s_a[7] = " Ambikapur | Antagarh | Arang | Bacheli | Bagbahera | Bagicha | Baikunthpur | Balod | Balodabazar | Balrampur | Barpalli | Basana | Bastanar | Bastar | Bderajpur | Bemetara | Berla | Bhairongarh | Bhanupratappur | Bharathpur | Bhatapara | Bhilai | Bhilaigarh | Bhopalpatnam | Bijapur | Bilaspur | Bodla | Bokaband | Chandipara | Chhinagarh | Chhuriakala | Chingmut | Chuikhadan | Dabhara | Dallirajhara | Dantewada | Deobhog | Dhamda | Dhamtari | Dharamjaigarh | Dongargarh | Durg | Durgakondal | Fingeshwar | Gariaband | Garpa | Gharghoda | Gogunda | Ilamidi | Jagdalpur | Janjgir | Janjgir-Champa | Jarwa | Jashpur | Jashpurnagar | Kabirdham-Kawardha | Kanker | Kasdol | Kathdol | Kathghora | Kawardha | Keskal | Khairgarh | Kondagaon | Konta | Korba | Korea | Kota | Koyelibeda | Kuakunda | Kunkuri | Kurud | Lohadigundah | Lormi | Luckwada | Mahasamund | Makodi | Manendragarh | Manpur | Marwahi | Mohla | Mungeli | Nagri | Narainpur | Narayanpur | Neora | Netanar | Odgi | Padamkot | Pakhanjur | Pali | Pandaria | Pandishankar | Parasgaon | Pasan | Patan | Pathalgaon | Pendra | Pratappur | Premnagar | Raigarh | Raipur | Rajnandgaon | Rajpur | Ramchandrapur | Saraipali | Saranggarh | Sarona | Semaria | Shakti | Sitapur | Sukma | Surajpur | Surguja | Tapkara | Toynar | Udaipur | Uproda | Wadrainagar";
s_a[8] = " Amal | Amli | Bedpa | Chikhli | Dadra & Nagar Haveli | Dahikhed | Dolara | Galonda | Kanadi | Karchond | Khadoli | Kharadpada | Kherabari | Kherdi | Kothar | Luari | Mashat | Rakholi | Rudana | Saili | Sili | Silvassa | Sindavni | Udva | Umbarkoi | Vansda | Vasona | Velugam ";
s_a[9] = " Brancavare | Dagasi | Daman | Diu | Magarvara | Nagwa | Pariali | Passo Covo ";
s_a[10] = " Central Delhi | East Delhi | New Delhi | North Delhi | North East Delhi | North West Delhi | South Delhi | South West Delhi | West Delhi ";
s_a[11] = " Canacona | Candolim | Chinchinim | Cortalim | Goa | Jua | Madgaon | Mahem | Mapuca | Marmagao | Panji | Ponda | Sanvordem | Terekhol ";
s_a[12] = " Ahmedabad | Ahwa | Amod | Amreli | Anand | Anjar | Ankaleshwar | Babra | Balasinor | Banaskantha | Bansada | Bardoli | Bareja | Baroda | Barwala | Bayad | Bhachav | Bhanvad | Bharuch | Bhavnagar | Bhiloda | Bhuj | Billimora | Borsad | Botad | Chanasma | Chhota Udaipur | Chotila | Dabhoi | Dahod | Damnagar | Dang | Danta | Dasada | Dediapada | Deesa | Dehgam | Deodar | Devgadhbaria | Dhandhuka | Dhanera | Dharampur | Dhari | Dholka | Dhoraji | Dhrangadhra | Dhrol | Dwarka | Fortsongadh | Gadhada | Gandhi Nagar | Gariadhar | Godhra | Gogodar | Gondal | Halol | Halvad | Harij | Himatnagar | Idar | Jambusar | Jamjodhpur | Jamkalyanpur | Jamnagar | Jasdan | Jetpur | Jhagadia | Jhalod | Jodia | Junagadh | Junagarh | Kalawad | Kalol | Kapad Wanj | Keshod | Khambat | Khambhalia | Khavda | Kheda | Khedbrahma | Kheralu | Kodinar | Kotdasanghani | Kunkawav | Kutch | Kutchmandvi | Kutiyana | Lakhpat | Lakhtar | Lalpur | Limbdi | Limkheda | Lunavada | M.M.Mangrol | Mahuva | Malia-Hatina | Maliya | Malpur | Manavadar | Mandvi | Mangrol | Mehmedabad | Mehsana | Miyagam | Modasa | Morvi | Muli | Mundra | Nadiad | Nakhatrana | Nalia | Narmada | Naswadi | Navasari | Nizar | Okha | Paddhari | Padra | Palanpur | Palitana | Panchmahals | Patan | Pavijetpur | Porbandar | Prantij | Radhanpur | Rahpar | Rajaula | Rajkot | Rajpipla | Ranavav | Sabarkantha | Sanand | Sankheda | Santalpur | Santrampur | Savarkundla | Savli | Sayan | Sayla | Shehra | Sidhpur | Sihor | Sojitra | Sumrasar | Surat | Surendranagar | Talaja | Thara | Tharad | Thasra | Una-Diu | Upleta | Vadgam | Vadodara | Valia | Vallabhipur | Valod | Valsad | Vanthali | Vapi | Vav | Veraval | Vijapur | Viramgam | Visavadar | Visnagar | Vyara | Waghodia | Wankaner ";
s_a[13] = " Adampur Mandi | Ambala | Assandh | Bahadurgarh | Barara | Barwala | Bawal | Bawanikhera | Bhiwani | Charkhidadri | Cheeka | Chhachrauli | Dabwali | Ellenabad | Faridabad | Fatehabad | Ferojpur Jhirka | Gharaunda | Gohana | Gurgaon | Hansi | Hisar | Jagadhari | Jatusana | Jhajjar | Jind | Julana | Kaithal | Kalanaur | Kalanwali | Kalka | Karnal | Kosli | Kurukshetra | Loharu | Mahendragarh | Meham | Mewat | Mohindergarh | Naraingarh | Narnaul | Narwana | Nilokheri | Nuh | Palwal | Panchkula | Panipat | Pehowa | Ratia | Rewari | Rohtak | Safidon | Sirsa | Siwani | Sonipat | Tohana | Tohsam | Yamunanagar ";
s_a[14] = " Amb | Arki | Banjar | Bharmour | Bilaspur | Chamba | Churah | Dalhousie | Dehra Gopipur | Hamirpur | Jogindernagar | Kalpa | Kangra | Kinnaur | Kullu | Lahaul | Mandi | Nahan | Nalagarh | Nirmand | Nurpur | Palampur | Pangi | Paonta | Pooh | Rajgarh | Rampur Bushahar | Rohru | Shimla | Sirmaur | Solan | Spiti | Sundernagar | Theog | Udaipur | Una";
s_a[15] = " Akhnoor | Anantnag | Badgam | Bandipur | Baramulla | Basholi | Bedarwah | Budgam | Doda | Gulmarg | Jammu | Kalakot | Kargil | Karnah | Kathua | Kishtwar | Kulgam | Kupwara | Leh | Mahore | Nagrota | Nobra | Nowshera | Nyoma | Padam | Pahalgam | Patnitop | Poonch | Pulwama | Rajouri | Ramban | Ramnagar | Reasi | Samba | Srinagar | Udhampur | Vaishno Devi ";
s_a[16] = " Bagodar | Baharagora | Balumath | Barhi | Barkagaon | Barwadih | Basia | Bermo | Bhandaria | Bhawanathpur | Bishrampur | Bokaro | Bolwa | Bundu | Chaibasa | Chainpur | Chakardharpur | Chandil | Chatra | Chavparan | Daltonganj | Deoghar | Dhanbad | Dumka | Dumri | Garhwa | Garu | Ghaghra | Ghatsila | Giridih | Godda | Gomia | Govindpur | Gumla | Hazaribagh | Hunterganj | Ichak | Itki | Jagarnathpur | Jamshedpur | Jamtara | Japla | Jharmundi | Jhinkpani | Jhumaritalaiya | Kathikund | Kharsawa | Khunti | Koderma | Kolebira | Latehar | Lohardaga | Madhupur | Mahagama | Maheshpur Raj | Mandar | Mandu | Manoharpur | Muri | Nagarutatri | Nala | Noamundi | Pakur | Palamu | Palkot | Patan | Rajdhanwar | Rajmahal | Ramgarh | Ranchi | Sahibganj | Saraikela | Simaria | Simdega | Singhbhum | Tisri | Torpa ";
s_a[17] = " Afzalpur | Ainapur | Aland | Alur | Anekal | Ankola | Arsikere | Athani | Aurad | Bableshwar | Badami | Bagalkot | Bagepalli | Bailhongal | Bangalore | Bangalore Rural | Bangarpet | Bantwal | Basavakalyan | Basavanabagewadi | Basavapatna | Belgaum | Bellary | Belthangady | Belur | Bhadravati | Bhalki | Bhatkal | Bidar | Bijapur | Biligi | Chadchan | Challakere | Chamrajnagar | Channagiri | Channapatna | Channarayapatna | Chickmagalur | Chikballapur | Chikkaballapur | Chikkanayakanahalli | Chikkodi | Chikmagalur | Chincholi | Chintamani | Chitradurga | Chittapur | Cowdahalli | Davanagere | Deodurga | Devangere | Devarahippargi | Dharwad | Doddaballapur | Gadag | Gangavathi | Gokak | Gowribdanpur | Gubbi | Gulbarga | Gundlupet | H.B.Halli | H.D. Kote | Haliyal | Hampi | Hangal | Harapanahalli | Hassan | Haveri | Hebri | Hirekerur | Hiriyur | Holalkere | Holenarsipur | Honnali | Honnavar | Hosadurga | Hosakote | Hosanagara | Hospet | Hubli | Hukkeri | Humnabad | Hungund | Hunsagi | Hunsur | Huvinahadagali | Indi | Jagalur | Jamkhandi | Jewargi | Joida | K.R. Nagar | Kadur | Kalghatagi | Kamalapur | Kanakapura | Kannada | Kargal | Karkala | Karwar | Khanapur | Kodagu | Kolar | Kollegal | Koppa | Koppal | Koratageri | Krishnarajapet | Kudligi | Kumta | Kundapur | Kundgol | Kunigal | Kurugodu | Kustagi | Lingsugur | Madikeri | Madugiri | Malavalli | Malur | Mandya | Mangalore | Manipal | Manvi | Mashal | Molkalmuru | Mudalgi | Muddebihal | Mudhol | Mudigere | Mulbagal | Mundagod | Mundargi | Murugod | Mysore | Nagamangala | Nanjangud | Nargund | Narsimrajapur | Navalgund | Nelamangala | Nimburga | Pandavapura | Pavagada | Puttur | Raibag | Raichur | Ramdurg | Ranebennur | Ron | Sagar | Sakleshpur | Salkani | Sandur | Saundatti | Savanur | Sedam | Shahapur | Shankarnarayana | Shikaripura | Shimoga | Shirahatti | Shorapur | Siddapur | Sidlaghatta | Sindagi | Sindhanur | Sira | Sirsi | Siruguppa | Somwarpet | Sorab | Sringeri | Sriniwaspur | Srirangapatna | Sullia | T. Narsipur | Tallak | Tarikere | Telgi | Thirthahalli | Tiptur | Tumkur | Turuvekere | Udupi | Virajpet | Wadi | Yadgiri | Yelburga | Yellapur ";
s_a[18] = " Adimaly | Adoor | Agathy | Alappuzha | Alathur | Alleppey | Alwaye | Amini | Androth | Attingal | Badagara | Bitra | Calicut | Cannanore | Chetlet | Ernakulam | Idukki | Irinjalakuda | Kadamath | Kalpeni | Kalpetta | Kanhangad | Kanjirapally | Kannur | Karungapally | Kasargode | Kavarathy | Kiltan | Kochi | Koduvayur | Kollam | Kottayam | Kovalam | Kozhikode | Kunnamkulam | Malappuram | Mananthodi | Manjeri | Mannarghat | Mavelikkara | Minicoy | Munnar | Muvattupuzha | Nedumandad | Nedumgandam | Nilambur | Palai | Palakkad | Palghat | Pathaanamthitta | Pathanamthitta | Payyanur | Peermedu | Perinthalmanna | Perumbavoor | Punalur | Quilon | Ranni | Shertallai | Shoranur | Taliparamba | Tellicherry | Thiruvananthapuram | Thodupuzha | Thrissur | Tirur | Tiruvalla | Trichur | Trivandrum | Uppala | Vadakkanchery | Vikom | Wayanad ";
s_a[19] = " Agatti Island | Bingaram Island | Bitra Island | Chetlat Island | Kadmat Island | Kalpeni Island | Kavaratti Island | Kiltan Island | Lakshadweep Sea | Minicoy Island | North Island | South Island ";
s_a[20] = " Agar | Ajaigarh | Alirajpur | Amarpatan | Amarwada | Ambah | Anuppur | Arone | Ashoknagar | Ashta | Atner | Babaichichli | Badamalhera | Badarwsas | Badnagar | Badnawar | Badwani | Bagli | Baihar | Balaghat | Baldeogarh | Baldi | Bamori | Banda | Bandhavgarh | Bareli | Baroda | Barwaha | Barwani | Batkakhapa | Begamganj | Beohari | Berasia | Berchha | Betul | Bhainsdehi | Bhander | Bhanpura | Bhikangaon | Bhimpur | Bhind | Bhitarwar | Bhopal | Biaora | Bijadandi | Bijawar | Bijaypur | Bina | Birsa | Birsinghpur | Budhni | Burhanpur | Buxwaha | Chachaura | Chanderi | Chaurai | Chhapara | Chhatarpur | Chhindwara | Chicholi | Chitrangi | Churhat | Dabra | Damoh | Datia | Deori | Deosar | Depalpur | Dewas | Dhar | Dharampuri | Dindori | Gadarwara | Gairatganj | Ganjbasoda | Garoth | Ghansour | Ghatia | Ghatigaon | Ghorandogri | Ghughari | Gogaon | Gohad | Goharganj | Gopalganj | Gotegaon | Gourihar | Guna | Gunnore | Gwalior | Gyraspur | Hanumana | Harda | Harrai | Harsud | Hatta | Hoshangabad | Ichhawar | Indore | Isagarh | Itarsi | Jabalpur | Jabera | Jagdalpur | Jaisinghnagar | Jaithari | Jaitpur | Jaitwara | Jamai | Jaora | Jatara | Jawad | Jhabua | Jobat | Jora | Kakaiya | Kannod | Kannodi | Karanjia | Kareli | Karera | Karhal | Karpa | Kasrawad | Katangi | Katni | Keolari | Khachrod | Khajuraho | Khakner | Khalwa | Khandwa | Khaniadhana | Khargone | Khategaon | Khetia | Khilchipur | Khirkiya | Khurai | Kolaras | Kotma | Kukshi | Kundam | Kurwai | Kusmi | Laher | Lakhnadon | Lamta | Lanji | Lateri | Laundi | Maheshwar | Mahidpurcity | Maihar | Majhagwan | Majholi | Malhargarh | Manasa | Manawar | Mandla | Mandsaur | Manpur | Mauganj | Mawai | Mehgaon | Mhow | Morena | Multai | Mungaoli | Nagod | Nainpur | Narsingarh | Narsinghpur | Narwar | Nasrullaganj | Nateran | Neemuch | Niwari | Niwas | Nowgaon | Pachmarhi | Pandhana | Pandhurna | Panna | Parasia | Patan | Patera | Patharia | Pawai | Petlawad | Pichhore | Piparia | Pohari | Prabhapattan | Punasa | Pushprajgarh | Raghogarh | Raghunathpur | Rahatgarh | Raisen | Rajgarh | Rajpur | Ratlam | Rehli | Rewa | Sabalgarh | Sagar | Sailana | Sanwer | Sarangpur | Sardarpur | Satna | Saunsar | Sehore | Sendhwa | Seondha | Seoni | Seonimalwa | Shahdol | Shahnagar | Shahpur | Shajapur | Sheopur | Sheopurkalan | Shivpuri | Shujalpur | Sidhi | Sihora | Silwani | Singrauli | Sirmour | Sironj | Sitamau | Sohagpur | Sondhwa | Sonkatch | Susner | Tamia | Tarana | Tendukheda | Teonthar | Thandla | Tikamgarh | Timarani | Udaipura | Ujjain | Umaria | Umariapan | Vidisha | Vijayraghogarh | Waraseoni | Zhirnia ";
s_a[21] = " Achalpur | Aheri | Ahmednagar | Ahmedpur | Ajara | Akkalkot | Akola | Akole | Akot | Alibagh | Amagaon | Amalner | Ambad | Ambejogai | Amravati | Arjuni Merogaon | Arvi | Ashti | Atpadi | Aurangabad | Ausa | Babhulgaon | Balapur | Baramati | Barshi Takli | Barsi | Basmatnagar | Bassein | Beed | Bhadrawati | Bhamregadh | Bhandara | Bhir | Bhiwandi | Bhiwapur | Bhokar | Bhokardan | Bhoom | Bhor | Bhudargad | Bhusawal | Billoli | Brahmapuri | Buldhana | Butibori | Chalisgaon | Chamorshi | Chandgad | Chandrapur | Chandur | Chanwad | Chhikaldara | Chikhali | Chinchwad | Chiplun | Chopda | Chumur | Dahanu | Dapoli | Darwaha | Daryapur | Daund | Degloor | Delhi Tanda | Deogad | Deolgaonraja | Deori | Desaiganj | Dhadgaon | Dhanora | Dharani | Dhiwadi | Dhule | Dhulia | Digras | Dindori | Edalabad | Erandul | Etapalli | Gadhchiroli | Gadhinglaj | Gaganbavada | Gangakhed | Gangapur | Gevrai | Ghatanji | Golegaon | Gondia | Gondpipri | Goregaon | Guhagar | Hadgaon | Hatkangale | Hinganghat | Hingoli | Hingua | Igatpuri | Indapur | Islampur | Jalgaon | Jalna | Jamkhed | Jamner | Jath | Jawahar | Jintdor | Junnar | Kagal | Kaij | Kalamb | Kalamnuri | Kallam | Kalmeshwar | Kalwan | Kalyan | Kamptee | Kandhar | Kankavali | Kannad | Karad | Karjat | Karmala | Katol | Kavathemankal | Kedgaon | Khadakwasala | Khamgaon | Khed | Khopoli | Khultabad | Kinwat | Kolhapur | Kopargaon | Koregaon | Kudal | Kuhi | Kurkheda | Kusumba | Lakhandur | Langa | Latur | Lonar | Lonavala | Madangad | Madha | Mahabaleshwar | Mahad | Mahagaon | Mahasala | Mahaswad | Malegaon | Malgaon | Malgund | Malkapur | Malsuras | Malwan | Mancher | Mangalwedha | Mangaon | Mangrulpur | Manjalegaon | Manmad | Maregaon | Mehda | Mekhar | Mohadi | Mohol | Mokhada | Morshi | Mouda | Mukhed | Mul | Mumbai | Murbad | Murtizapur | Murud | Nagbhir | Nagpur | Nahavara | Nanded | Nandgaon | Nandnva | Nandurbar | Narkhed | Nashik | Navapur | Ner | Newasa | Nilanga | Niphad | Omerga | Osmanabad | Pachora | Paithan | Palghar | Pali | Pandharkawada | Pandharpur | Panhala | Paranda | Parbhani | Parner | Parola | Parseoni | Partur | Patan | Pathardi | Pathari | Patoda | Pauni | Peint | Pen | Phaltan | Pimpalner | Pirangut | Poladpur | Pune | Pusad | Pusegaon | Radhanagar | Rahuri | Raigad | Rajapur | Rajgurunagar | Rajura | Ralegaon | Ramtek | Ratnagiri | Raver | Risod | Roha | Sakarwadi | Sakoli | Sakri | Salekasa | Samudrapur | Sangamner | Sanganeshwar | Sangli | Sangola | Sanguem | Saoner | Saswad | Satana | Satara | Sawantwadi | Seloo | Shahada | Shahapur | Shahuwadi | Shevgaon | Shirala | Shirol | Shirpur | Shirur | Shirwal | Sholapur | Shri Rampur | Shrigonda | Shrivardhan | Sillod | Sinderwahi | Sindhudurg | Sindkheda | Sindkhedaraja | Sinnar | Sironcha | Soyegaon | Surgena | Talasari | Talegaon S.Ji Pant | Taloda | Tasgaon | Thane | Tirora | Tiwasa | Trimbak | Tuljapur | Tumsar | Udgir | Umarkhed | Umrane | Umrer | Urlikanchan | Vaduj | Velhe | Vengurla | Vijapur | Vita | Wada | Wai | Walchandnagar | Wani | Wardha | Warlydwarud | Warora | Washim | Wathar | Yavatmal | Yawal | Yeola | Yeotmal ";
s_a[22] = " Bishnupur | Chakpikarong | Chandel | Chattrik | Churachandpur | Imphal | Jiribam | Kakching | Kalapahar | Mao | Mulam | Parbung | Sadarhills | Saibom | Sempang | Senapati | Sochumer | Taloulong | Tamenglong | Thinghat | Thoubal | Ukhrul ";
s_a[23] = " Amlaren | Baghmara | Cherrapunjee | Dadengiri | Garo Hills | Jaintia Hills | Jowai | Khasi Hills | Khliehriat | Mariang | Mawkyrwat | Nongpoh | Nongstoin | Resubelpara | Ri Bhoi | Shillong | Tura | Williamnagar";
s_a[24] = " Aizawl | Champhai | Demagiri | Kolasib | Lawngtlai | Lunglei | Mamit | Saiha | Serchhip";
s_a[25] = " Dimapur | Jalukie | Kiphire | Kohima | Mokokchung | Mon | Phek | Tuensang | Wokha | Zunheboto ";
s_a[26] = " Anandapur | Angul | Anugul | Aska | Athgarh | Athmallik | Attabira | Bagdihi | Balangir | Balasore | Baleswar | Baliguda | Balugaon | Banaigarh | Bangiriposi | Barbil | Bargarh | Baripada | Barkot | Basta | Berhampur | Betanati | Bhadrak | Bhanjanagar | Bhawanipatna | Bhubaneswar | Birmaharajpur | Bisam Cuttack | Boriguma | Boudh | Buguda | Chandbali | Chhatrapur | Chhendipada | Cuttack | Daringbadi | Daspalla | Deodgarh | Deogarh | Dhanmandal | Dharamgarh | Dhenkanal | Digapahandi | Dunguripali | G. Udayagiri | Gajapati | Ganjam | Ghatgaon | Gudari | Gunupur | Hemgiri | Hindol | Jagatsinghapur | Jajpur | Jamankira | Jashipur | Jayapatna | Jeypur | Jharigan | Jharsuguda | Jujumura | Kalahandi | Kalimela | Kamakhyanagar | Kandhamal | Kantabhanji | Kantamal | Karanjia | Kashipur | Kendrapara | Kendujhar | Keonjhar | Khalikote | Khordha | Khurda | Komana | Koraput | Kotagarh | Kuchinda | Lahunipara | Laxmipur | M. Rampur | Malkangiri | Mathili | Mayurbhanj | Mohana | Motu | Nabarangapur | Naktideul | Nandapur | Narlaroad | Narsinghpur | Nayagarh | Nimapara | Nowparatan | Nowrangapur | Nuapada | Padampur | Paikamal | Palla Hara | Papadhandi | Parajang | Pardip | Parlakhemundi | Patnagarh | Pattamundai | Phiringia | Phulbani | Puri | Puruna Katak | R. Udayigiri | Rairakhol | Rairangpur | Rajgangpur | Rajkhariar | Rayagada | Rourkela | Sambalpur | Sohela | Sonapur | Soro | Subarnapur | Sunabeda | Sundergarh | Surada | T. Rampur | Talcher | Telkoi | Titlagarh | Tumudibandha | Udala | Umerkote ";
s_a[27] = " Bahur | Karaikal | Mahe | Pondicherry | Purnankuppam | Valudavur | Villianur | Yanam ";
s_a[28] = " Abohar | Ajnala | Amritsar | Balachaur | Barnala | Batala | Bathinda | Chandigarh | Dasua | Dinanagar | Faridkot | Fatehgarh Sahib | Fazilka | Ferozepur | Garhashanker | Goindwal | Gurdaspur | Guruharsahai | Hoshiarpur | Jagraon | Jalandhar | Jugial | Kapurthala | Kharar | Kotkapura | Ludhiana | Malaut | Malerkotla | Mansa | Moga | Muktasar | Nabha | Nakodar | Nangal | Nawanshahar | Nawanshahr | Pathankot | Patiala | Patti | Phagwara | Phillaur | Phulmandi | Quadian | Rajpura | Raman | Rayya | Ropar | Rupnagar | Samana | Samrala | Sangrur | Sardulgarh | Sarhind | SAS Nagar | Sultanpur Lodhi | Sunam | Tanda Urmar | Tarn Taran | Zira ";
;

function print_state(state_id) {
    // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
    var option_str = document.getElementById(state_id);
    option_str.length = 0;
    option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select State', '');
    option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
        option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(state_arr[i], state_arr[i]);
    }
}

function print_city(city_id, city_index) {
    var option_str = document.getElementById(city_id);
    option_str.length = 0;  // Fixed by Julian Woods
    option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select City', '');

    option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
    var city_arr = s_a[city_index].split("|");
    for (var i = 0; i < city_arr.length; i++) {
        option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(city_arr[i], city_arr[i]);
    }
}

I wish to pass the value of the selected State and City to my controller in my Spring boot App, I am unable to do so, However I created this function and it helps me get the value
function getValues() {
    var stateValue = document.getElementById('sts').value;
    var cityValue = document.getElementById('state').value;

    alert(stateValue);
    alert(cityValue);
}

But I am unable to pass this to my Spring Boot MVC controller, I have tried using @RequestParam("stateValue") String stateValue, but it does not work.

The @RequestParam annotations look at the name attributes of your <select>.  The first one is named name="stt" and the second one doesn't have a name.  You need to give your second attribute a name and then use those as your @RequestParams
<select name="stt" ... /> should correspond to @RequestParam("stt") String state
<select name="city" ... /> should correspond to @RequestParam("city") String city
(Or however you want to name them.)

this did it
```
@PostMapping("/updateDetails")
    public String addDetails(@ModelAttribute("employeeDetails") EmployeeDetails employeeDetails,
            @RequestParam("address1") String address1, @RequestParam("address2") String address2,
            @RequestParam("passedValue") int empID, @RequestParam(value = "stt") String stateValue,
            @RequestParam(value = "city") String cityValue) {
        employeeDetails.setState(stateValue);
        employeeDetails.setCity(cityValue);
        String completeAddressString = address1.concat(" " + address2);
        employeeDetails.setAddress(completeAddressString);
        System.out.println(employeeDetails);

        return "NextStage";
    }

HTML+thymeleaf code 

```
<div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">State</label> <select
                        onchange="print_city('state', this.selectedIndex);" id="sts"
                        name="stt" class="form-control" required>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="inputCity" class="form-label">City</label> <select
                        id="state" class="form-control" name="city" required>
                        <option>Select State First</option>
                    </select>
                    <script language="javascript">
                        print_state("sts");
                    </script>
                </div>
```

